# how to generate a textbox with a close button dynamically using DOM in Javascript by clicking on a link?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
           //generate is the onclick function of the link//
          function generate(){
          var text = document.createElement('input');
          var buttn = document.createElement('button');
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <a href="#" onclick="generate()">add contact</a>
     // link which will generate the textbox with button when clicked//
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

A textbox should generate using javascript(DOM) with a button when we click on the link.
when we click on the button i want to remove the textbox and the button.
Continous click on the link also want to generate n number of textboxes with close button

Answer (score 1):

You're halfway there. You need to set a type for your `input` element, and set some text for your `button` element. Once you have done that, you can append the button and text input to your form. To do this, you can get the form using `document.getElementById('myForm')`, and then using `appendChild()` to append the text and button element.

```css
input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    //generate is the onclick function of the link//
    function generate() {
      var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
      var text = document.createElement('input');
      text.type="text";
      var button = document.createElement('button');
      button.innerText = "Click me";
      form.appendChild(text);
      form.appendChild(button);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <a href="#" onclick="generate()">add contact</a> // link which will generate the textbox with button when clicked//
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Element creation is only the first step. You have to somehow insert the created element into HTML with one of `append(), prepend(), appendChild()` methods. All of them insert a created `node`. But you also can just add an HTML string into another element: `parent.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div><input><button>...</button></div>");` — this method is preferred, if you want to insert too complex code.

By the way, one of the possible solutions:

```js
let add = document.getElementById('add-new-input');
let form = document.getElementById('myForm');

add.onclick = addNewInput;

form.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let target = e.target; // the clicked element
  /* Google → JS event delegation */
  if ( target.classList.contains('delete') ) {
    target.parentNode.outerHTML = "";
  }
});

function addNewInput() {
  let input = create('input');
  let button = create('button', "bubu");
  let del = create('button', "X", "delete");
  let div = create('div',"", "input-block");
  
  div.append( input, button, del );
  form.appendChild( div );
}

function create(tag, text, className){
  let node = document.createElement(tag);
 
  node.className = className || "";
  node.textContent = text || "";
  
  return node;
}
```

```css
/* Google → CSS-counter */

.input-block {
  counter-increment: bubu;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.input-block button { margin-left: 5px; }

.delete { color: red; cursor: pointer; }

.input-block::before {
  content: counter(bubu) ". ";
  color: #045acf;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return false;">
  <a href="#" id="add-new-input">add contact</a>
</form>
```